# Share Image and link together in google plus

Tags: android, google-plus, sharing

In my application I have to share title, image and , and link. I have coded as follows that.

```
public void shareOnGooglePlus(Uri uri) {

    PlusShare.Builder shareBuilder = new PlusShare.Builder(this);
    shareBuilder.setType("text/plain");

    shareBuilder.setText("title");

    if (uri != null) {
        String mime = getContentResolver().getType(uri);                              
        shareBuilder.setContentUrl(Uri.parse("my_url_to_publish"));           
        shareBuilder.addStream(uri);
        shareBuilder.setType(mime);
    }
    Intent shareIntent = shareBuilder.getIntent();

    try {
        startActivityForResult(shareIntent, SHARE_GOOGLE_PLUS_REQUEST_CODE);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ane) {
        ToastUtils.SHOW(this, getString(R.string.google_plus_not_installed));
    }
}
```

the probelm with this is it is not showing the content uri, if I removed the stream from that, then it will show link.

how do I fix this ?

Comment: If you share a link then the corresponding image will be displayed automatically

Comment: image and link are independent

Answer (score 0):

**add this :**

shareBuilder.setContentDeepLinkId("testID",
                    "Test Title",
                    "Test Description",
                    Uri.parse("my_url_to_publish"))

**in place of :**

shareBuilder.setContentUrl(Uri.parse("my_url_to_publish"));

Comment: where is the image link then ?